# axis2 client Trying to write END_DOCUMENT when document has no root (ie. trying to output empty document) error

Tags: encryption, apache-axis, ws-security

I have a legacy WebServiceProject which connects to ws-security enabled web service using axis2 & rampart.

Here is my axis2.xml:

```
<parameter name="OutflowSecurity">
    <action>
        <items>Timestamp UsernameToken Encrypt Signature</items>
        <user>myUser</user>
        <passwordCallbackClass>tr.com.mypackage.PWCBHandler</passwordCallbackClass>
        <signaturePropFile>crypto.properties</signaturePropFile>  
        <signatureKeyIdentifier>IssuerSerial</signatureKeyIdentifier>
    </action>
</parameter>
<parameter name="InflowSecurity">
    <action>
        <items>Timestamp Encrypt Signature</items>
        <user>myUser</user>
        <passwordCallbackClass>tr.com.mypackage.PWCBHandler</passwordCallbackClass>
        <signaturePropFile>crypto.properties</signaturePropFile>  
        <signatureKeyIdentifier>IssuerSerial</signatureKeyIdentifier>
    </action>
</parameter>
```

I am preparing the test environment and correctly set the crypto.properties and didn't change any code because it works fine at production and I am unfamiliar with axis2.
Here is my error message:

> [WARN] No transportReceiver for
>   org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServletListener found. An instance
>   for HTTP will be configured automatically. Please update your
>   axis2.xml file!
>
> C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat
>   9.0\webapps\WebServiceProject\WEB-INF
>
> 20-May-2020 15:19:01.862 SEVERE [https-jsse-nio-443-exec-1]
>
> org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun Error
>   running socket processor
>           java.lang.NullPointerException
>                   at org.bouncycastle.crypto.signers.PSSSigner.generateSignature(Unknown
>   Source)
>                   at org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.JDKPSSSigner.engineSign(Unknown Source)
>                   at java.base/java.security.Signature$Delegate.engineSign(Signature.java:1403)
>                   at java.base/java.security.Signature.sign(Signature.java:712)
>                   at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateVerify$T13CertificateVerifyMessage.(CertificateVerify.java:930)
>                   at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateVerify$T13CertificateVerifyProducer.onProduceCertificateVerify(CertificateVerify.java:1110)
>                   at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateVerify$T13CertificateVerifyProducer.produce(CertificateVerify.java:1103)
>                   at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.produce(SSLHandshake.java:440)
>                   at java.base/sun.security.ssl.ClientHello$T13ClientHelloConsumer.goServerHello(ClientHello.java:1252)
>                   at java.base/sun.security.ssl.ClientHello$T13ClientHelloConsumer.consume(ClientHello.java:1188)
>                   at java.base/sun.security.ssl.ClientHello$ClientHelloConsumer.onClientHello(ClientHello.java:851)
>                   at java.base/sun.security.ssl.ClientHello$ClientHelloConsumer.consume(ClientHello.java:812)
>                   at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:396)
>                   at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:444)
>                   at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask$DelegatedAction.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:1260)
>                   at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask$DelegatedAction.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:1247)
>                   at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:691)
>                   at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:1192)
>                   at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SecureNioChannel.tasks(SecureNioChannel.java:443)
>                   at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SecureNioChannel.handshakeUnwrap(SecureNioChannel.java:507)
>                   at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SecureNioChannel.handshake(SecureNioChannel.java:238)
>                   at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1575)
>                   at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>                   at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
>                   at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
>                   at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>                   at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830)

And the bottom of the trace:

> Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: Trying to write
>   END_DOCUMENT when document has no root (ie. trying to output empty
>   document).
>           at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BaseStreamWriter.throwOutputError(BaseStreamWriter.java:1473)
>           at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BaseStreamWriter.reportNwfStructure(BaseStreamWriter.java:1502)
>           at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BaseStreamWriter.finishDocument(BaseStreamWriter.java:1663)
>           at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BaseStreamWriter.close(BaseStreamWriter.java:288)
>           at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.wrapper.XMLStreamWriterWrapper.close(XMLStreamWriterWrapper.java:46)
>           at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.MTOMXMLStreamWriter.close(MTOMXMLStreamWriter.java:222)
>           at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMSerializableImpl.serializeAndConsume(OMSerializableImpl.java:192)
>           at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.SOAPMessageFormatter.writeTo(SOAPMessageFormatter.java:74)
>           ... 54 more

It looks like it is unable to find some kind of signature. But I am pretty sure I've made all the changes correctly.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same exception when I tried to set up HTTPS Connector (with TLS 1.3) on Tomcat 9.0.16 and Open JDK 11.0.8 on linux x64. I was using BouncyCastle (BC) v1.63 in my WebApp Lib.

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.bouncycastle.crypto.signers.PSSSigner.generateSignature(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.rsa.PSSSignatureSpi.engineSign(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.security.Signature$Delegate.engineSign(Signature.java:1404)
    at java.base/java.security.Signature.sign(Signature.java:713)
```

This error has been notified by BC Community.
Regarding this BC's issues, it's was clear that I needed to upgrade my BC libs:

- https://github.com/bcgit/bc-java/pull/632
- https://github.com/bcgit/bc-java/pull/633

I upgraded webapp dependencies with BC 1.66, now it works perfectly with OpenJDK 11.0.8.